# Add leading zeros in an OLEDB Command Statement

Tags: vb.net, select, oledbcommand

I am trying to add a leading zero to primary keys that are only 5 characters in my dataset. Our primary key is 6 characters and the leading zero is being cut off from an Excel file I am receiving. I want to add the leading zero in the command statement below, but it cannot recognize the "CONVERT" function. I am still new and do not know a similar function to use. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
("SELECT (SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Primary #]),6)) AS [Primary #],[Gourmet #],[Unit],FROM [" + sheetName + "]", con)
```

Full code below

```
Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection("Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=xxx;Password=xxxxxx")
        sqlCon.Open()


        Dim excelCmd2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT (SELECT RIGHT('000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Primary #]),6)) AS [Primary #],[Gourmet #],[Unit] FROM [" + sheetName + "]", con)
        Dim excelRead As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
        excelRead.SelectCommand = excelCmd2
        excelRead.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        excelRead.Fill(dt2)
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

The Datagridview allows me to see what is in the Datatable to make sure those extra zeros occur. Afterwards the dataset from my excelCmd2 has all its columns equal parameters in my sql table as so:

```
Using dataRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = excelCmd2.ExecuteReader()
                If dataRead.HasRows() Then
                    While dataRead.Read()
                        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
                        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
                        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlUpdate

                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@primary", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item("Primary #"))
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@spc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item("Gourmet #"))
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@unit", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item("Unit"))
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
```

Comment: What is the type of the `[Primary #]` column in the database? What is the database program? Does the primary key *really* need to be six characters?

Comment: [Primary #] is coming out of an Excel file and it is either text or a number format depending on the file (The sender is inconsistent). I will upload it into my SQL database as a varchar(6).

Comment: I suggest reading the values in as they are, then using `Cstr(primaryId).PadLeft(6, "0"c)` to convert it to a string before inserting it into the database. Is the DataGridView necessary? - if not, it is just complicating things.

Comment: The Datagridview allows me to see what is in the Datatable to make sure those extra zeros occur. Afterwards the dataset from my excelCmd2 has all its columns equal parameters in my sql table as you can see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it won't enable you to see the leading zeros being added, you can change your line

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@primary", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item("Primary #")
```

to

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@primary", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item("Primary #").PadLeft(6, "0"c)
```

to add the required leading zeros, which means your SELECT command is simplified to

```
"SELECT [Primary #], [Gourmet #], [Unit] FROM [" & sheetName & "]"
```

(The string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.)

Comment: I removed a spurious comma from before `FROM`, in case that is in your actual code.

Comment: Your fix in the parameter adding portion of my code worked wonderfully. I do not understand the difference in {&} and {+} though as I have never ran into an issue yet with using {+} to concatenate string. I will research this more. Thank you friend!

Answer (score 0):

Use Padleft to add leading zeros.

```
primaryId.padleft(6, "0")
```

Or if its not already formatted as a string

```
 primaryid.tostring.padleft(6, "0")
```

Since you are wanting to use the padded version in your command text, you will probably want to create a temporary string variable to hold the new value, just to help code readability.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this in my code. My column name in the dataset is [Primary #]. How would I pad everything under the column name [Primary #] in my Select Command or by the means you are describing?

Comment: you will go ahead and read your 5 digit number out of your Excel file like normal, with no conversion.  Then, when you do your INSERT statement, you would insert the value "primaryId.padleft(6, "0")"